# Problemas al implementar un metodo

Tags: java

Estoy implementando un método `sendMessage` pero no consigo hacer lo que quiero.

Tengo dos clases una llamada `User`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User implements CompetitionListener {
    private Platform platform;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
    private List<Message> inbox;
    private List<Message> outbox;
    private List<Submission> submissions;

    public User (Platform platform, String username, String password, String fullName) {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: User constructor needed for user registration
        */
        this.platform = platform;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.inbox = new ArrayList<Message>();
        this.outbox = new ArrayList<Message>();
        this.submissions = new ArrayList<Submission>();
    }

    public User (User obj) {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.3: Implementation of the copy constructor
        */
        this.platform = obj.platform;
        this.username = obj.username;
        this.password = obj.password;
        this.fullName = obj.fullName;
        this.inbox = obj.inbox;
        this.outbox = obj.outbox;
        this.submissions = obj.submissions;
    }

    public Boolean checkPassword(String password) {   
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.2: Implementation of checkPassword, required by login
        */
        return this.password.equals(password);        
    }

    public Organizer asOrganizer() {   
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.3: Create a new object for the Organizer Role
        */
        return new Organizer(this);
    }

    public Participant asParticipant() {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.3: Create a new object for the Participant Role
        */
        return new Participant(this);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: Required by method findUser
        */
        return this.username;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: Required by test
        */
        return this.fullName;
    }

    public String toString() {        
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    sb.append(getFullName()).append("<").append(getUserName()).append(">");     
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.2: Required by test
        */
        if(obj==null) {
            return false;
        }        
        if (obj instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) obj;
            if (!this.username.equals(user.username) || !this.password.equals(user.password) || !this.fullName.equals(user.fullName)) {
                return false;
            }        
            // Additional checks can be added
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages() {        
        return null;
    }

    public Message sendMessage(String to, String subject, String message) throws CompetitionException {  

        if (to == null) {
            throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.RECIPIENT_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Message m = new Message(this, this, subject, message);
        return m;
    }


    public List<Competition> myCompetitions() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Message> getInbox() {        
        return this.inbox;
    }

    public List<Message> getOutbox() {        
        return this.outbox;
    }    

    public Platform getPlatform() {        
        return this.platform;
    }

    public void onNewEvaluation() {

    }
    public void onCompetitionClosed() {

    }
}
```

Y otra llamada `Platform`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Platform {
    private List<User> users;
    private List<Competition> competitions;

    public Platform() {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: We need to initialize the list of users
        */
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    private User findUser(String username) { 
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: Implementation of method findUser to find a user in the list users by username
        */
        User user = null;

        Iterator<User> itr = this.users.iterator();      
        while(itr.hasNext() && user == null) {
            User u = itr.next();
            if(u.getUserName().equals(username)) {
                user = u;
            }
        }

        return user;
    }

    public User registerUser(String username, String password, String fullname)   {        
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: Register a new user, checking that it does not exist 
        */
        User newUser = null;

        // Check if the user is new or already exists
        User queryUser = findUser(username);

        if(queryUser==null) {
            newUser = new User(this, username, password, fullname);
            this.users.add(newUser);
        }

        return newUser;
    }

    public User login(String username, String password) {    
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.2: Login an already existing user
        */
        User user = null;

        // Find the user in the list of registered users
        User queryUser = findUser(username);        

        // If the user exists, check the password
        if(queryUser!=null && queryUser.checkPassword(password)) {
            user = queryUser;
        }

        return user;        
    }    

    public Integer getNumUsers() {
        /**
         * PR1 Ex 2.1: Required for test, to check if a new user is registered 
        */
        return this.users.size();
    }

    public Integer getNumCompetitions() {        
        return null;
    }

    public Message sendMessage(User from, String to, String subject, String message) throws CompetitionException {               
        return null;
    }

    public void registerCompetition(Competition competition) {

    }    

    public List<Competition> getOpenCompetitions() {        
        return null;
    }

    private void evaluateAll() {

    }

    public void run() {
        // Simulates system call for evaluation
        evaluateAll();
    }
}
```

El caso es que el método `User#sendMessage` recibe 3 parámetros `to`, `subject`, `message` y este mensaje debe ser enviado a su destinatario. El método delega el envío a `Platform#sendMessage`.

Quiero que el sistema compruebe que el parámetro `to` que envía el correo sea correcto (no `null` y que exista en la plataforma), si no salta una excepción.
Esta parte la tengo casi echa ya que si es `null` lanzo la excepción pero si no lo es no se cómo plantear la búsqueda y ver si existe o no.

Del mismo modo, se verificará en el destinatario que existe en la plataforma y que la información pasada es correcta, si no te lanzara una excepción.

La primera parte la tengo planteada asi:

`User#sendMessage`:

```
    public Message sendMessage(String to, String subject, String message) throws CompetitionException {  
    if (to == null) {
        throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.RECIPIENT_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    Message m = new Message(this, this, subject, message);
    return m;
}
```

¿Cómo busco luego si el `to` ya existe o no para lanzar la excepción o seguir con el mensaje?

Añado a la pregunta que el método sendMessage de la clase PLATFORM debe pasar estas pruebas y por eso lo declaro de esa manera:

```
    // Send a message from a not registered user
    User u_test=new User(platform, "not_registered", "a password", "Unregistered User");
    try {
        u_test.sendMessage(username2, msg_subject1, msg_body1);            
        fail();
    } catch (CompetitionException ce) {
        assertEquals(ce.getMessage(), CompetitionException.SENDER_NOT_FOUND);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estoy asumiendo (basado en los comentarios de tu clase `Platform`) que esta se encarga de mantener el registro de usuarios. Por los mismos comentarios veo que existe un método en esta clase que se llama `findUser` que recibe como parámetro un objeto de tipo `String` correspondiente al username de un usuario y que retorna un objeto de tipo `User` al recorrer todos los usuarios en el `ArrayList` de esa clase. Basado en esto una solución posible es:

```
 public Message sendMessage(String to, String subject, String message) throws CompetitionException {  

    User receiver = platform.findUser(to);
    if (to == null) {
        throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.RECIPIENT_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    else if(receiver == null ) {
        throw new Exception(); //Aquí debes lanza el tipo de excepción apropiado de tu lógica de negocio
    }
    Message m = new Message(this, this, subject, message);
    return m;
}
```

Cada objeto de tipo `User` se instancia con al menos un objeto de tipo `Platform`, de acuerdo a los constructores que definiste. La clase `Platform` ofrece un método llamado `findUser` que de acuerdo a los comentarios 'busca un `User` a partir de su username' y retorna ese objeto. De acuerdo a la implementación, si el objeto existe lo retorna exitosamente, caso contrario retorna null, por lo que en el método `sendMessage` podemos invocarlo y verificar si ha devuelto null, en cuyo caso sabemos que el usuario no existe y lanzamos la excepción apropiada.

Mencionas en la preguntas que finalmente delegas el envío del mensaje en el método `sendMessage` de la clase `Platform`, pero no encuentro evidencia de que sea así, incluso, por la firma de este método no encuentro sentido a que instancies un objeto de tipo `Message`. Incluso, en la firma de este método se puede ver que ni siquiera usas el objeto de tipo `User` creado. Puedo sugerir que cambies la firma del método `sendMessage` de la clase `Platform` para que acepte dos objetos de tipo `User` (quien envía y quien recibe) y un objeto de tipo `Message` (el mensaje que construyes):

```
public Message sendMessage(User from, User to, String subject, Message message) throws CompetitionException {               
    //Implementación
}
```

Y que en el método `sendMessage` de la clase `User` invoques a este método (para hacer efectiva la delegación).

Comment: Funciona todo correctamente pero se me olvido poner el test que paso para el método sendMessage de la clase platform,quizas asi tenga algo mas de sentido.